# Am not able to test for actions, and therefore cannot update Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

My main problem is I am confused on where to implement the listener classes so that whenever an action is made (whether it be a key press or mouse click) the applet is updated.  I realize my compiling issue is from my CanvasPanel method in my CanvasPanel class and not having arguments in my actionPerformed method. However at this point I'm not sure how these listeners should be implemented correctly.  Have tried looking over different questions already posted, so sorry if it is a duplicate.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class WholePanel extends JPanel
{
   private Color foregroundColor, backgroundColor;
   private int currentDiameter, x1, y1;
   private CanvasPanel canvas;
   private JPanel buttonPanel;

   private JRadioButton filledRadio, unfilledRadio;
   private JRadioButton redRadio, greenRadio;
   private boolean fill;
   private Graphics myCircle;

   public WholePanel()
   {
      backgroundColor = Color.CYAN;
      foregroundColor = Color.RED;

      currentDiameter = 100;
      x1 = 200; y1 = 100;

      unfilledRadio = new JRadioButton("Unfilled", true);
      filledRadio = new JRadioButton("Filled", false);
      redRadio = new JRadioButton("Red", true);
      greenRadio = new JRadioButton("Green", false);

      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.add(unfilledRadio);
      buttonPanel.add(filledRadio);
      buttonPanel.add(redRadio);
      buttonPanel.add(greenRadio);

      canvas = new CanvasPanel();

      JSplitPane sPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, buttonPanel, canvas);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(sPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

   private class ColorListener implements ActionListener
    {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
          if (redRadio.isSelected()) {
              greenRadio.setSelected(false);
              backgroundColor = Color.RED;
          }
          else if (greenRadio.isSelected()) {
              redRadio.setSelected(false);
              backgroundColor = Color.GREEN;
          }
          // ...extra else/if statements
      }
    } // end of ColorListener


   private class FillListener implements ActionListener
    {
     private boolean fill;

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
            if (filledRadio.isSelected()) {
                unfilledRadio.setSelected(false);
                fill = true;
                paintComponent(myCircle);
            }
            else if (unfilledRadio.isSelected()) {
                filledRadio.setSelected(false);
                fill = false;
                paintComponent(myCircle);
            }
      }
    }

   private class CanvasPanel extends JPanel
    {
     public CanvasPanel( )
      {
        addKeyListener(new DirectionListener());
        addMouseListener(new PointListener());

        setBackground(backgroundColor);

        //This method needs to be called for this panel to listen to keys
        //When panel listens to other things, and go back to listen
        //to keys, this method needs to be called again.

        ColorListener.actionPerformed();
        FillListener.actionPerformed();
        requestFocus();
      }


     public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
      {
          super.paintComponent(page);
          setBackground(backgroundColor);

          page.setColor(foregroundColor);
          page.drawOval(x1, y1, currentDiameter, currentDiameter);
          if (fill == true) { 
              page.fillOval(x1, y1, currentDiameter, currentDiameter);
          }
      }

     /** This method is overriden to enable keyboard focus */
     public boolean isFocusable()
      {
        return true;
      }

     private class DirectionListener implements KeyListener 
       {
         public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
          {
            currentDiameter = 100;
            x1 = 200; y1 = 100;
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            // switch statement here

            }
          }
       } // end of DirectionListener


     public class PointListener implements MouseListener
       {
         public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event)
          {
            canvas.requestFocus();
          }

         public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event) {}
         public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent event) {}
         public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent event) {}
         public void mouseExited (MouseEvent event) {}

       } // end of PointListener

    } // end of Canvas Panel Class

} // end of Whole Panel Class
```

Comment: Please shrink that code down to a manageable [mcve]. There's so much code there, most of it not relevant to your problem. Please read the link.

Comment: I took out the main panel-making method, as it was mostly unnecessary.  The rest I left in because the four classes are what I'm trying to implement in my CanvasPanel class

Comment: Please read or re-read the link, as that's not what I'm asking. Yes, we **need** the main method, and we need code we can compile and run, just a lot less of it.

Comment: Also check out the [sscce](http://sscce.org) for perhaps a better explanation of this tool. Doing this correctly will require effort on your part, but it's effort that is worth while for you and for us as it will distill your problem to its essence.

Comment: Whoa -- you're not painting correctly. You should not be giving your classes a Graphics field and should never call `paintComponent(...)` directly. Java graphics is done indirectly. Start over and change the state of your GUI and call `repaint()` and let the paintComponent use the changed fields to do the drawing.

Comment: You will want to go through the Swing graphics tutorials to see how it should be done. Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: Ok so I took many unnecessary buttons and if/else statements out.  My main problem lies with the implementation of the DirectionListener, PointListener, FillListener, and ColorListener in the CanvasPanel method of the CanvasPanel class.  Does that help? Also I will look at your recently made comments and see how I can change that!

Comment: Bottom line: your code has been written without your looking at any Swing tutorial, and you're making stuff up as you go, and that's not going to work. Read the Swing tutorials and they will guide you as to how to add action listeners, mouse listeners, and such. You can find them here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  It may seem like I was writing as I was going, and to some extent it's true.  However, I researched this topic for hours yesterday before I even started.  Apparently, that was not enough.  I'll try to fix the issues with my code, but it seems it is not as easy as changing a few lines.  I need to rethink the foundation for some of this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some major problems in that code:

- You're calling paintComponent directly, something you should never do. Instead change a state field of your class, call `repaint()`and then have paintComponent use the state field to decide what it should paint.
- Same for using a Graphics field -- don't. Instead only use the Graphics object given to your paintComponent method by the JVM. The [Swing Graphics tutorial will explain this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).
- You're trying to call your listener call back methods directly, which is the exact opposite of how listeners are supposed to work and negates the benefits of using listeners. Instead ***ADD*** your listeners to the components that will use them -- including adding the ActionListeners to the buttons that need them, the KeyListeners to the components that need them, MouseListeners... etc...

For instance, let's look at a **much** simpler example, one that uses two JRadioButtons and that's it:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PartialPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 650;
    private static final int CIRC_W = 200;
    private int circleX = 300;
    private int circleY = 200;
    private Color circleColor = null;
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    private JRadioButton blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue");
    private JRadioButton redButton = new JRadioButton("Red");

    public PartialPanel() {
        ColorListener colorListener = new ColorListener();
        blueButton.addActionListener(colorListener);
        redButton.addActionListener(colorListener);

        buttonGroup.add(blueButton);
        buttonGroup.add(redButton);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(blueButton);
        buttonPanel.add(redButton);

        add(buttonPanel);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (circleColor != null) {
            g.setColor(circleColor);
            g.fillOval(circleX, circleY, CIRC_W, CIRC_W);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        } else {
            return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
        }
    }

    private class ColorListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == blueButton) {
                circleColor = Color.BLUE;
            } else if (e.getSource() == redButton) {
                circleColor = Color.RED;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        PartialPanel mainPanel = new PartialPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PartialPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here we add a ColorListener to the JRadioButtons. In the listener, we change the state of the class's circColor field, and then call repaint(). The paintComponent method then uses circColor's value to decide what color to use when drawing a circle.

Comment: Thanks this is a great place to start my fixes.  I appreciate the time you took to break it down for me

Comment: @JordanPagni: you're welcome. Please look at the simplified version above, one that deals with just **one** listener -- but the concepts are the same. You add the listener to the component that's being listened to, you change the state of the class in the listener and call repaint, you have the paintComponent method use the state fields (here just circColor, and circleX and circleY) to decide what to paint and where.